# Active member of a union created directly through memcpy() or std::bit_cast()?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, unions

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <bit>

union U
{
    uint64_t ull;
    int32_t i[2];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint64_t x = argc;
    U u;
    if (true)
        u = std::bit_cast<U>(x);
    else
        ::memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof(x));
    auto r = u.i[0];
    r += u.i[1];
    r += u.ull;
    return r;
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Which member of `u` is active immediately before to the `auto r = ...` line?
2. Which line(s) have undefined behavior (if any), and why?
3. Does flipping `true` to `false` change the answers above, and if so how/why?

Comment: I don't think the "active" concept plays a role here.  `r` is going to be defined as an `int32_t`, so the `r += s.ull` should trigger a "loss of precision" warning.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Yeah, I'm not worried about loss of precision; I'm just worried about potential UB here.

Comment: Well, I need more coffee, you used a `union` and then `S s` which my dyslexic brain said `struct`. So No, there is no padding concern, no *indeterminate bit/value* and no UB.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Ah, I'll change it to `U` to make that clearer.

Comment: Chuckling -- it's funny how the mind works (especially an aging tired one). I read `union` then somehow convinced myself it was a struct. It always comes back to *human fallibility* `:)` My reading of [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) says you are safe.

Comment: There was a time when the layout of a union was the wild, wild west -- virtually no guarantees -- and your code would definitely have been undefined.  That has mostly been locked down now, since virtually every real-life compiler did the sensible thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which member of u is active immediately before to the auto r = ... line?

The default-initialized `u` does not have any active member.

`std::bit_cast` implicitly creates objects nested within the returned object. A member will be active only if `std::bit_cast`'s implicit object creation starts the lifetime of one of the subobjects. Implicit object creation is specified to do this only if that would give the program execution defined behavior.

However, regardless of which subobject's member implicit object creation would start the lifetime, either `r += u.i[1];` or `r += u.ull;` would have undefined behavior for reading the inactive member.

Therefore, the program has undefined behavior regardless and no member of `u` is active.

> Which line(s) have undefined behavior (if any), and why?

Individual lines cannot have undefined behavior. Either the whole program has undefined behavior (for given input) or it doesn't.

With all lines present the program has undefined behavior, but removing either those accessing `u.ull` or those accessing `u.i` will give the program defined behavior, because implicit object creation of `std::bit_cast` will make the other member active. (Assuming that copy-assignment of the union is intended to make the same member active in the destination as is active in the source. The specification for that doesn't seem clear to me. See e.g. discussion in https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/5193.)

> Does flipping true to false change the answers above, and if so how/why?

The same problem remains. `memcpy` also implicitly creates objects nested in the destination by the same rules.

---

Furthermore, depending on the input and implementation-defined representations of the involved types, `r += u.i[1];` may cause undefined behavior regardless of the above for overflow on signed integral arithmetic.

Comment: @user541686 That's my understanding, yes, except for some uncertainties with operations on unions in general, e.g. regarding the assignment: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/5193